# In Perl, how do I put multiple class in a single .pm file

Tags: perl, moose

I have a question of Perl [MooseX::Declare](https://metacpan.org/pod/MooseX%3A%3ADeclare). I want to put multiple classes in a single .pm file. How do I make this file, and what will the filename be because that .pm file has multiple classes?

For example

```
use MooseX::Declare;
class Point {

   has 'x' => ( isa => 'Num', is => 'rw' );
   has 'y' => ( isa => 'Num', is => 'rw' );

   method clear {
      $self->x(0);
      $self->y(0);
   }
   method set_to( Num $x, Num $y) {
      $self->x($x);
      $self->y($y);
   }
}


class Point3D {

   has 'z' => ( isa => 'Num', is => 'rw' );

   method clear {
      $self->z(0);
   }
   method set_to( Num $x, Num $y, Num $z) {
      $self->x($x);
      $self->y($y);
      $self->z($z);
   }
}
```

How do I save this pm file -- by first class name or second class name?

Answer (score 4):

Since the one-file-per-class guideline is merely there to help you organize your own code, you can name the file anything you want.

That said, **there's a good reason that guideline exists.**

There's an interesting discussion on this topic over at [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=932351) that you may want to review.

I would advise against multiple classes per file, unless you're putting them in a common namespace.

```perl
{
    package Geometrics;

    class Point {
        ...
    }

    class Point3D {
        ...
    }
}
```

Should you go that route, you could name your `.pm` file accordingly (i.e., `Geometrics.pm`).

Failing that, assuming your classes are related by theme (as they seem to be), perhaps something like `Points.pm` would be appropriate.

**Edit**:

As for how to "call or use class (Point, Point3D) from outside" or how to instantiate classes defined in your module:

```perl
# import the package
use Geometrics qw(Point Point3d);
# or
# use Geometrics ('Point' 'Point3d');


# instantiate a Point
my $point = Point->new();

# instantiate a Point3D
my $point3d = Point3D->new();
```

You could also import the package by doing either:

```perl
# import the package but do not import any symbols from it
use Geometrics ();
```

or

```perl
# While you can import the package this way, please do not do so.
# import the package with ALL symbols
use Geometrics;
```

but there are going to be some caveats to doing so...

```perl
# importing the package with no symbols
use Geometrics ();

# means instantiation of objects must be fully-qualified
my $point = Geometrics::Point->new();
my $point3d = Geometrics::Point3D->new();
```

```perl
# importing the package with ALL symbols
use Geometrics;

# makes instantiation of objects simpler
my $point = Point->new();
my $point3d = Point3D->new();

# BUT because all symbols are imported with the package,
# overwriting of symbols can occur too easily.
# If I were to import the package Foo this way (which has the symbol Bar defined)
use Foo;

# and then import the package Baz this way (which also has the symbol Bar defined)
use Baz;

# I no longer have access to Foo:Bar as that has been over-written by Baz::Bar
# because I imported the packages with ALL symbols by default.
# The lesson here is to code defensively and:
#     only import those symbols you intend to use, or
#     don't import any symbols and fully-qualify everything.
```

Comment: Lower case names are intended for pragmas though.

Comment: Dear pete,  thanks for response. but how to call or use class (Point, Point3D) from outside or another perl code, how to make object for class's.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule do not put multiple classes in one file.

The exception I am used to seeing most often is related classes, especially helper or sub classes of the top level class.  In those cases they have always been grouped into a single package and the file name being the package name.